# Flutter - Customly Sort the Current Playing Playlist ( just_audio)

Tags: flutter, dart

I have been trying to find a way to sort the current playing playlist by every metadata extracted with [flutter_media_metadata](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_media_metadata) but so far with no luck.

Is there a way to do it using [just_audio](https://pub.dev/packages/just_audio)?

Edit: here's how the media data is entered:

1: [Creating the playlist](https://github.com/ryanheise/just_audio/blob/f234a9a7681ea712a6a9d64590a601af0a6b2a38/just_audio/example/lib/example_playlist.dart#L27)

2: [Set the playlist to the player](https://github.com/ryanheise/just_audio/blob/f234a9a7681ea712a6a9d64590a601af0a6b2a38/just_audio/example/lib/example_playlist.dart#L96)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem by adding a sort function [in this abstract class](https://github.com/ryanheise/just_audio/blob/f234a9a7681ea712a6a9d64590a601af0a6b2a38/just_audio/lib/just_audio.dart#L3154) (ShuffleOrder) and then implementing it [here](https://github.com/ryanheise/just_audio/blob/f234a9a7681ea712a6a9d64590a601af0a6b2a38/just_audio/lib/just_audio.dart#L3178) (DefaultShuffleOrder). I also added a sort function [in this absctract class](https://github.com/ryanheise/just_audio/blob/f234a9a7681ea712a6a9d64590a601af0a6b2a38/just_audio/lib/just_audio.dart#L2023) (AudioSource) and I implemented it [in this class](https://github.com/ryanheise/just_audio/blob/f234a9a7681ea712a6a9d64590a601af0a6b2a38/just_audio/lib/just_audio.dart#L2275) (ConcatenatingAudioSource) and finally in the AudioPlayer class I added this sort function:

```dart
Future<void> sort(List<Song> songs, PlaylistSorting playlistSorting, {SortingOrder sortingOrder = SortingOrder.ascending}) async {
    if (_disposed) return;
    if (audioSource == null) return;
    _audioSource!._sort(songs, playlistSorting, sortingOrder: sortingOrder);
    _updateShuffleIndices();
    await (await _platform).setShuffleOrder(SetShuffleOrderRequest(audioSourceMessage: _audioSource!._toMessage()));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably something you need to add yourself. You can take the list of songs in the playlist and write functions to sort them based on each property.

For example:

```
List<Songs> sortByTitle(List<Songs> playlist, bool isDescending = True) {
  if(isDescending) {
    playlist = playlist.sort((b, a) => a.compareTo(b));
  } else {
    playlist = playlist.sort((a, b) => a.compareTo(b));
  }
  return playlist;
}
```

Where the list you pass in is a list of titles or whatever metadata you are trying to sort by.

See https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.17.0/dart-core/List/sort.html for more information on the sort method.

Comment: I have tried something similar to that but just_audio isn't designed as simple as that.

Comment: Can you edit your question to provide an example of the data you are wanting to sort and how you are collecting that data?

Comment: I have included the two lines of code in the just_audio example that shows that

Comment: My answer still applies, you just need to access the elements of the list differently. You have a list of AudioSource objects being passed to children of ConcatenatingAudioSource. You would just need to sort the list before passing it to ConcatenatingAudioSource.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55285324/sort-a-list-of-objects-in-dart does a good job of explaining how to sort objects. Unfortunately, I don't know much about this package but just looking through the source code, it doesn't seem like they have a built in sort method.

Comment: I can do the sorting as I already have a function that sorts the songs but the problem is that I also need to sort after I pass the AudioSource objects  to the children of ConcatenatingAudioSource, I need to sort the songs in the playlist while a song from playlist is actively playing. I tried to sort the children of ConcatenatingAudioSource but that didn't change the order in which the songs where being played

Comment: Solved the problem, see my answer. Thanks for the effort in trying to help. Appreciated.